# Why use done channel

Tags: go, asynchronous, goroutine

It's not the first time I can see this kind of code and I don't understand the meaning of the `done` chan:

```
// Context: this code will "watch" a file and react when the file has been changed
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

func main() {
    // create a new watcher
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // close the watcher when the function exits
    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                // monitor write event.
                // You can add more events supported by fsnotify
                if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    fmt.Println("Modified symlink:", event.Name)
                }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("Error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    // add your symbolic link path and file to monitor
    err = watcher.Add("/tmp/file")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

I think that this channel is here to stop the main (==keep the soft alive as well as the goroutine). In this case why can't we use the `sync` package which was made for that purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: *"I think that this channel is here to stop the main"* -- correct.

Comment: You can use a `sync.WaitGroup`, this just chooses not to, but the goroutine doesn't return so it doesn't matter. You could also `select{}` or anything else that blocks.

Comment: This isn't a good example of the pattern, because nothing closes the channel.

Comment: There isn't even a reason for the goroutine here, put the blocking portion of the code at the end of main.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's not the first time I see this kind if method, I have always supposed that the sync package was the right way to do it. Does this method have pros (except that it takes less code) ?

Comment: This channel blocks the main, absence of it causes the main goroutine to exit immediately after running. sync package has waitGroup to do a job sync, this pattern needs an async one.